# From where the header-text can be changed in WordPress custom header?

Tags: php, theme-customizer, custom-header, header-image

I am developing a small theme as I am beginner. I am setting up `custom-header` using `add_theme_support()` function. From there I can change the header image in the front end. Ok, so far is good. Now In codex of the WordPress ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers ) there is `$defaults` arguments for the `custom-header` to enable some features. I can use most of them, but when I use the `header-text` I thought I should get option in the customizer (backend) to change the text. But I did not get. But I am sure that option remains where I do not know.

Anyone please suggests some to know

1. from where the header-text can be changed?
2. to show in the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`header-text`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-headers/#header-text) option in the custom header allows you to switch off the header text, not to change its content.

You can change the header text in the customizer. To show it in your front end you must must use `echo get_bloginfo('name')` for the blog title and `echo get_bloginfo('description')` for the tagline.